# how to find a square in a given set of points?

Tags: c++, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-systems

In a coordinate plane,you are given a set of points,say 10 points,lets consider them to be integers for the sake of simplicity.how to find out if a possible square lies within these 10 points?....if not, how many points to be added to these set of points to have atleast one square?

Comment: Well, it's a maximum of two points that'd need to be added.

Comment: if only 1 point is given,then 3 points have to be added

Comment: You just said there were 10 given points.

Comment: if the grammar is correct,i have used the word 'say'....and what if all the points lie on the same point?

Comment: Then they already form a square.

Comment: understandable, but not solution to the posed hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

Just use brute force. For each point in the set, for each possible other point in the set, check if there are two points close enough to possible other square corners. If the coordinates are integers then this is really simple (although with quadratic complexity, assuming constant time for the point look up), when floating point a bit less simple with a little higher complexity, probably.

Comment: a brute force approach would be to calculate "nC2" distances and compare,but that will not help me arrive at how many more points may be required.

Comment: @peterburke: Yes it will.  In the case you find a square, the answer is 0.  In the case you find one corner, then the answer is 1.  In the case you find no corners, then the answer is 2.

Comment: you can in O(N) complexity group colinear points that form 45* angle with X axis, and optimize this brute force to points in the same group. that being said, for every two points in the same group just check if there are two other points at required coordinates missing to form the square